# exchangeability vs. shift invariance

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, stationary-processes

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of real RVs indexed by $n \geq 0$.  Can someone provide an example of a sequence $X_n$ that is exchangeable (law invariant under finitely supported permutations on the natural numbers) but not shift invariant (law invariant under left shift)?  What about the other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sequence $(X_n)$ is exchangeable then $(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n,X_{n+1})$ and $(X_2,\ldots,X_n,X_{n+1},X_1)$ coincide in distribution, in particular $(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{n})$ and $(X_2,\ldots,X_{n+1})$ coincide in distribution. This holds for every $n\geqslant1$ hence  $(X_n)$ is shift invariant. Thus, exchangeability implies shift invariance.

Let $X_0$ denote a nondegenerate symmetric random variable and $X_n=(-1)^nX_0$ for every $n$. Then $(X_n)$ is shift invariant but the distributions of $(X_1,X_2)$ and $(X_1,X_3)$ are different hence $(X_n)$ is not exchangeable.
Thus, shift invariance does not imply exchangeability.